# Selecting JSON nodes from a heavily nested external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, object

I'm working with a local json file and attempting to render certain nodes from it. The reason why I'm asking about it on StackOverflow, however, is that the json file itself is heavily nested with a ton of child nodes, and I don't know how to traverse a json file like this one. I flattened the data in an attempt to mitigate the problem, but it didn't seem to do much good.

I'm trying to access the `__text` specifically (i.e. `__text": "Guides ＆ Protocols"`)

#### Here's a sample of the data:

```
{
    "feed": {
        "id": "[redacted]",
        "title": "",
        "updated": "2019-01-17T21:01:03Z",
        "entry": [
            {
                "id": "Web/Lists(guid'[redacted]')/Items(1)",
                "category": {
                    "_term": "[redacted]",
                    "_scheme": "[redacted url]"
                },
                "link": {
                    "_rel": "edit",
                    "_href": "Web/Lists(guid'[redacted]')/Items(1)"
                },
                "title": "",
                "updated": "2019-01-17T21:01:03Z",
                "author": {
                    "name": ""
                },
                "content": {
                    "properties": {
                        "ResourceType": {
                            "element": {
                                "Label": {
                                    "__prefix": "d",
                                    "__text": "Guides ＆ Protocols" <--------------------
                                },
                                "TermGuid": {
                                    "__prefix": "d",
                                    "__text": "[redacted]"
                                },
                                "WssId": {
                                    "_m:type": "[redacted]",
                                    "__prefix": "d",
                                    "__text": "706"
                                },
                                "__prefix": "d"
                            },
                            "_m:type": "Collection([redacted])",
                            "__prefix": "d"
                        },
                        "__prefix": "m"
                    },
                    "_type": "application/xml"
                },
                "_m:etag": "\"2\""
            }
         ...
     ]
 }
```

#### JavaScript:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from 'axios';

import myJSONfile from '../../../public/myJSONfile.json';
import tinyJsonFlat from '../../../public/tinyJsonFlat.json'; // Top 10, ResourceTypes only

import { basename } from 'path';


    export default class {
        constructor() {
            $('<div class="test-div">testing</div>').appendTo(document.body);

            this.loadData();
        }


        loadData() {
            var data = tinyJsonFlat // syntax seems off

            var result = $.map(data.data, function(obj) {
                return obj.Label + obj.__text

                $(document.body).append(result);
                console.log(result);
                // $('#site-labels').text(JSON.stringify(tinyJsonFlat)); /// earlier solution
            });

        }

    }
```

Comment: `obj.feed.entry[0].content.properties.ResourceType.element.Label.__text`

Answer (score 0):

When you parse a JSON file, it behaves just like a normal Javascript object, then:

```
myJSONfile.feed.entry[index].content.properties.ResourceType.element.Label.__text
```

Pay attention to the index of the entry you are getting access to:

```
myJSONfile.feed.entry[index]
```

```js
const json = {
  "feed": {
    "id": "[redacted]",
    "title": "",
    "updated": "2019-01-17T21:01:03Z",
    "entry": [
      {
        "id": "Web/Lists(guid'[redacted]')/Items(1)",
        "category": {
          "_term": "[redacted]",
          "_scheme": "[redacted url]"
        },
        "link": {
          "_rel": "edit",
          "_href": "Web/Lists(guid'[redacted]')/Items(1)"
        },
        "title": "",
        "updated": "2019-01-17T21:01:03Z",
        "author": {
          "name": ""
        },
        "content": {
          "properties": {
            "ResourceType": {
              "element": {
                "Label": {
                  "__prefix": "d",
                  "__text": "Guides ＆ Protocols"
                },
                "TermGuid": {
                  "__prefix": "d",
                  "__text": "[redacted]"
                },
                "WssId": {
                  "_m:type": "[redacted]",
                  "__prefix": "d",
                  "__text": "706"
                },
                "__prefix": "d"
              },
              "_m:type": "Collection([redacted])",
              "__prefix": "d"
            },
            "__prefix": "m"
          },
          "_type": "application/xml"
        },
        "_m:etag": "\"2\""
      }
    ]
  }
}
   
console.log(json.feed.entry[0].content.properties.ResourceType.element.Label.__text)
// Guides ＆ Protocols
```

Comment: Note that `ResourceType` and `Label` are capitalised.

Comment: You're right @RoryMcCrossan, I edited my answer fixing the typo. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info---it makes sense to "go down the line" and select those specific nodes. But unfortunately nothing's appeared :| Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/dc85723h/

Comment: I don't see the snipped yet... just a question, what index did you use?

Comment: I just did index of 0 as a test.

Comment: I edited my answer adding a working example... can you check it?

Comment: I didn't see your most recent comment till just now---let me take a look.

Comment: I updated the line `console.log(json.feed.entry[0]['content'].properties.ResourceType.element.Label.__text)` and can now see 'Guides & Protocols' in the console. I made the same ['content'] change to the return but nothing happened :|

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Array.prototype.findKey = function(key){

  let res = [];

  function traverseChildren(input, lookFor) {
    //By default, imagine what we are looking at is JSON...
    let children = Object.keys(input);
    //... however, if it is an array, just stick with that.
    if (Array.isArray(input)){
      children = input;
    }
    //Go through everything in the target
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      //Have we found the *key* we are looking for?
      if (children[i] === lookFor && Array.isArray(input)) {
        //If so, record the value.
        res.push(input[lookFor]);
      } else {
        //If not, keep searching.
        traverseChildren(input[children[i]]);
      }
    }
  }

  traverseChildren(this, key);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: I've added comments now which should explain how the code works, if that's OK.